# User Friendly Web-Based Front-End for Editing XML Data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm building a website for a restaurant and they want to be able to update their menu frequently.

I don't want to use a full-blown CMS, rather I would like to do something a lot more specific and simple.

I've decided on using an XML file to store the menu data. The XML structure is as follows:

```
<menudata>
<dish>
   <name>Seafood Linguini</name>
   <description>Scallops, shrimp, and lobster pieces on linguini in white sauce</description>
   <price>24.50</price>
</dish>
. . . <!-- more dishes -->
</menudata>
```

I've written PHP that gets the data and displays it.

Now I need to write ‘admin’ software that they can access and edit the data. I want it to be  *very limited*. Really, I want it to be just input fields on a blank page allowing access to editing each child of `<dish>`, a button to add a new `<dish>`, and a Save button. In an ideal world, I would like to write some JavaScript that would allow them to drag and drop the menu items into order (is that even possible?)

I am a designer, not a developer, and my PHP knowledge is limited — that said, I wrote the code for getting the XML file and echoing it into a proper HTML page in about an hour with just the php.net manual. I’m using the SimpleXML method.

So, if it’s something that’s not hard to do I can probably hack it together myself.

I have two questions:

1. Is what I want possible with PHP and SimpleXML? Would someone with little to no experience in PHP but a quick learner be able to do this on their own?
2. Is there software or code out there that I could adapt to my needs? I’ve looked around but have not found anything like it.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you did not want a CMS, but I would use drupal.org.

You will end up needed more features. How are you going to allow only certain people to edit the XML?
By doing the XML editing yourself you have to deal with issues with bad XML, unsafe data entered into the form etc.

Using a tool like drupal lets you concentrate on your design - not coding.

Comment: As you are stating, op will end up needing versioning, draft support, user authentcation, logging, and a myriad of other things.

Comment: Alright, well, I wouldn't need versioning and I was thinking of dealing with authentication by using htpasswd on a sub-domain, but bad XML and unsafe data are real concerns.
My hesitation with regards to CMSs is the level of freedom they give the user in terms of editing. I really just want them to be able to edit the data values, and **nothing else**. Is Drupal the best CMS for controlling that kind of thing?

Comment: Drupal has a nice capability to build custom content types. So you can build a "dish" content type with fields. So your users do not have to learn XML. You can add validation to each field, so the price can be a float, you can have an image field for photos of the food.